# How to run Webdriver.io heedlessly in node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

I am running this in node.js

```
//test.js
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
webdriverio
    .remote({desiredCapabilities: {browserName: 'firefox'}})
    .init()
    .url('https://www.google.com')
    .end()
```

But I get a FireFox browser with every iteration. Is there a way to run this without browser but have browser functionality (i.e. the browser doe not open).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should take a look at [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)
You'll want to download phantomjs and run your selenium server with the following argument: `-Dphantomjs.binary.path=PATH_TO_PHANTOMJS_EXE`

Then you'll want to start selenium with the following option:

```
{desiredCapabilities: {browserName: 'phantomjs'}}
```